# Display progress bar in the program's task bar icon

Tags: c#, windows-7, progress-bar, taskbar

I was seeing that when you do somethings at Windows 7 that haves a progress bar, things like downloading a file. You can see that in the programs bar, at the icon of the application, there is the progress of the file downloading, but it's possible to build applications that can do this?

Take a look at the Internet Explorer icon at my screenshot:
[Downloading... http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/5240/downa.png](http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/5240/downa.png)

Large version [here](http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/5240/downa.png).

Comment: Sorry, but C# is very good to me. **:D**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 7 progress bar in taskbar in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295890/windows-7-progress-bar-in-taskbar-in-c)

Comment: For people comming here that don't want to use external dependencies, go here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1295890/9867451

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

This has a lot of Windows Vista/7 features for .NET (C#/VB/etc.), including Task Bar Progress Bars.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you use the iTaskbarList3 interface, on which you call SetProgressState and SetProgressValue methods.

A more detailed overview on how to use the new Windows 7 taskbar functions is on the [Windows team blog](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/developers/archive/2009/07/28/windows-7-taskbar-dynamic-overlay-icons-and-progress-bars.aspx).