# Marquee progressbar in windows 7 taskbar

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, progress-bar

Is this possible? Would this be nice for the user?

I've already done some progressbars in the taskbar, so I'm not asking how to do it. I'm asking particularly about a marquee progressbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've did it successfully (in .NET 2.0) with the help of these two references:

- [Info on MSDN](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows7Taskbar/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2246)
- [Posting on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295890/windows-7-progress-bar-in-taskbar-in-c)

The marquee is done with the "Indeterminate" mode. An excerpt from my code [can be found here](http://pastebin.com/G2A0jGma).