# Is there a way to get 'Progress' value of a window?

Tags: c#, wpf, window

[image: A window with 'Progress' sample.]

I don't know what people call the GREEN thing above. Yes, the one that just like progress on `ProgressBar`. It usually appear on file transfer dialog and Video Player window. On Video Player window, that 'Progress' represent the video position.

Now, in my application, i want to do 'something' when the user has watched 75% of the duration.

Currently, i can approach this by reading the video duration and use `DispathcerTimer`. But, i found this not effective when the user pause the video.

So i came up with this idea, using that GREEN thing would be nice, because when the user pause the video, the 'Progress' also stop.

Is there a way to get the value of that 'Progress' ??

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295890/windows-7-progress-bar-in-taskbar-in-c

Comment: #Yushatak The API only provides a way to set the taskbar progress state :(

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize what you were trying to do - I read it too fast.

Answer (score 2):

The API only provides a way to *set* the taskbar progress state using the [`SetProgressState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391697(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`SetProgressValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391698(v=vs.85).aspx) functions, therefore you can't retrieve this value from the taskbar. The available .NET class (`TaskbarItemInfo`) is just a wrapper around this API.

As a workaround, you can embed a video player into your application so that you can control and keep track of the position yourself.