# Change windows application icon when certain event is triggered

Tags: c#, wpf, icons

I just use an existing example: When we logged into Microsoft Lync, if the status set is available, the icon of the application in the taskbar will appear green (a small box at the right bottom of the default icon). When set to busy, the icon will become red.

I want to apply this concept to my application. What I've done so far is when certain event is triggered, I change the application default icon to the desired icon like this:

```
myWindow.Icon = BitmapFrame.Create(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/Resources/desiredIcon.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)).Stream);
```

It worked for me. I just want to know besides this, is there any other better way to change the icon based on my situation. Or is it good enough for what I've done so far?

Answer (score 0):

In your incomplete code example, what is `app`? In WPF, the correct way to set an icon for a specific WPF window is to set the [`Window.Icon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.icon(v=vs.110).aspx) property. If your variable `app` is in fact a reference to the `Window` object for which you set the icon, then you seem to be doing the correct thing.

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing clearly what you are actually doing, it's not possible to say for sure.

Note that in Windows it is also possible to add an "overlay" to the window's icon. This is a different approach that is more useful for some cases. As far as I know, WPF does not provide any mechanism to access this Windows feature, but you can do it using COM interop with the Windows shell API. Some example code is shown here: [Windows 7 Taskbar SetOverlayIcon from WPF app doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1024786)

Comment: Hi @Peter, 'app' just the window's name, I should change to other name so wouldn't make any confusion